# Visualize HTTPS in WireShark

Tags: https, firebug, wireshark

I am trying to do a http bot to make me, my online check in.
I used the wireshark application to store the http request and response while i was 
make the check in.But when i try to visualize what was sent in the request/response i am not able to to see the https packets.
For example : If i use the firebug plugin (firefox) i am able to see this information:
This first link shows the headers(request/response)
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B9WcB03Ho2uzZmNlNTUyMDYtZjRhZC00YjljLTlkMDAtMDBiMmU4MDAzYjlk&hl=en_US
This second list shows the paylod of the POST method
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B9WcB03Ho2uzNjllYjllYTQtZTg2MS00Zjc1LTgyODQtNTUyNTc5YTk5N2Nh&hl=en_US

But in whireShark when i filter for example by the ip.dst_host , the only packets that appear are the TCP and TLSv1 and in each one i am not able to see the some information thar i am able to see in the firebug because that information is in the application layer(HTTP).

The URL : https://checkin.si.amadeus.net/1ASIHSSCWEBTP/sscwtp/checkindirect

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is explicitly designed to prevent you from seeing this traffic. If you have the server's private key, you can input it into WireShark to decrypt the packets. Otherwise, use Fiddler.

Comment: You do not need the private key of the server, only the session key as negotiated by the user agent (which can be derived from the [(pre-)master key](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27131)). You do need cooperation from the user agent (e.g. by dumping it via the standard-ish `SSLKEYLOGFILE` environment variable) or a memory scanner that can inspect the virtual memory of the user agent process. [Details and references](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL#Using_the_.28Pre.29-Master-Secret).

Comment: Sure, that works too, if you have a cooperative client.